# Magento 2: Sales Order report show wrong data

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2, sales-order, reports

Orders Report gives wrong results when compared with the actual orders. For example, in Dec 22,2017, there are total 5 orders having "complete" status.

[image]

But when I view orders report after applying filters then Magento shows only 1 order having complete status.

[image]

There are lots of such examples, I only mentioned one. I also noticed that Magento is not showing any order report after Dec, 2017 (There are many orders placed in 2018.)

Could you guys please help me to fix this?

Comment: Not even in orders but M2 gives precarious count (all most wrong) for shipment, invoices, refund..
Did someone find a solution?

Comment: First check you database,these 5 record are available or not.If available then please run this:
php bin/magento  setup:db-data:upgrade

Comment: Did you find any solution?